# Utilize Dropbox in Web API

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api2, dropbox-api

Not sure if this is really silly question, but is it possible to access / utilize the Dropbox within the scope of a web API.

Take the following into consideration. I have a multi-tenant front-end application written in Angular. The back-end (multi-tenant) in a C# web API. The user can upload documents / files. The API will be responsible for uploading the documents to the storage provider. In this case it's Dropbox. The thing is, I have read that Dropbox no longer supports username / password auth. Thus OAuth is used were by the user needs to provide consent to the calling application. This only has to happen once. Since multiple users within a single tenant can utilize the online storage, I'm struggling to see how this would work through a web API...

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Comment: If you're using the dropbox .NET SDK, I would take a look at the examples provided there. If you look at their simple blog demo you can see how they store access tokens for all users in the database, then when uploading a file, they retrieve the access token on the backend for the user who is doing the action and use that to authenticate the request to dropbox  https://github.com/dropbox/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/tree/master/dropbox-sdk-dotnet/Examples
I'm not positive if this is what you were looking for, but maybe it will help point you in the right direction...

Comment: @comradburk many thanks for the reply. So I can't just store one access token and use that for all the users? I just want to use one storage location for all users. Matter of fact, the root admin user sets up the dropbox instance. All the other users on the site doesn't need to know which storage provider is being used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can utilize 3rd party API inside Web API. I have never used Drop box API, but as you are saying they use OAuth as authentication mechanism i can show you the code which calls the 3rd party API in this case it is (clarifai).
i am using `HttpClient`you can use Dropbox .NET SDK. However if you want to stick to HTTP then [here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-from_oauth1) is the documentation for the same.

```
string token = "Oauth token received using some mechanism";    
string requestPath = string.Format("v1/tag");

HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.clarifai.com/");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestPath, content);
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var resString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    // JSON Response
    JObject resJsonObject = JObject.Parse(resString);

}
```

Now, As you have the concern to authenticate the user and get the token. [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#auth-token-from_oauth1) is Dropbox example in which they show how to redirect a user on dropbox website to authenticate and get the temporary oauth token.

- Take a look at `Connect` Action Method and `AuthAsync` Action Method in `Home` Controller.

Hope this helps you. If any doubt feel free to ask.

Comment: Just to understand the workings of the Auth better, is the following true. I create an app in dropbox. I refer to this app's id & secret in my site, when a user needs to grant permission / auth. The user grants permission that the app can manage files and folders. The site receives a token from the OAuth callback. Am I correct in saying the site can now manage the files at any time without having to auth again? Thanks!

Comment: @RichardBailey you are correct. I will recommend please check there documentation for OAuth i.e. the token you get from DropBox, what will be the expiry time of it. depending on the expiration time you might need to implement Refresh token

Comment: Just read this: _Do API access tokens expire?
App access tokens effectively don't expire, but users can manually revoke tokens by going into My apps. In the case of apps with app folder access, if the user deletes the app folder, your app's access token will no longer be valid. You should only process the authorization once, and save the access token for all future calls for that user. If an existing access token is invalid, (in which cases calls will return 401), you should prompt the user to re-authorize your app_ source: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/support

Comment: @RichardBailey you are on right path. I hope the above answer helped you.